# Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud, azure-keyvault, azure-automation

I'm following an educative course, where i need to put the webhook in the Azure Key Vault.

When i run below on powershell

```
New-AzKeyVault -Name "dev-avm-kvz" -ResourceGroupName "shared-rg" -Location "westeurope"
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "dev-avm-kvz" -UserPrincipalName "sxndgmail.onmicrosoft.com" -PermissionsToSecrets get,set,delete

$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString "https://8xe2c-bd3dc2a.webhook.we.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=i%2bcs1ZY" -AsPlainText -Force
$secret = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "dev-avm-kvz" -Name "db-new-vm-webhook" -SecretValue $secretvalue
```

The first line succeeds with a new vault created.
But the `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy` errors out as below -

[image: error]

here's the educative instructions im referring to ->

From their commands, i have changed principal name, vault name a little and my webhook URI

[image: instructions]

Comment: Your user principal name (`sxndgmail.onmicrosoft.com`) does not look right. It should be like `somename@sxndgmail.onmicrosoft.com`.

Comment: @GauravMantri same error with shivam01anand@gmail.onmicrosoft.com and shivam01anandgmail.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Is your tenant name `gmail.onmicrosoft.com`? UPN name should be `username@tenantname`.

Comment: @ShivamAnand It takes a while for the creation of Azure Key Vault to complete. You can try adding a delay after the first instruction(before Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy ). Using Start-sleep -Seconds 120  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment, and I got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/new-azkeyvault?view=azps-9.1.0):

Firstly, I have created a key Vault using the below PowerShell commands:

```
$ResourceGroupName ="XX"  
$Location="North Europe"  
$KeyVaultName="siliconvault"  
New-AzKeyVault -Name $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `  
-Location $Location -SoftDeleteRetentionInDays 7
```

[image]

Then, I have assigned access policy to the UPN and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-9.1.0):

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName siliconvault -UserPrincipalName 'XXk_outesaioutlook.onmicrosoft.com `  
-PermissionsToSecrets Get,Set,List
```

[image]

You can find the UPN of the user by visiting > Azure Active Directory in your Azure Portal > Left Pane > Users > Click on the desired User and Copy the UPN.

[image]

Then i have used below commands to add secrets of web uri:

```
$SecretVault=ConvertTo-SecureString "https://a.webhook.we.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=i%2"  -AsPlainText -Force

Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName siliconvault -Name "webhookuri" -SecretValue $SecretVault
```

[image]

Outputs:

Access Policy is assigned to the UPN successfully as below:

[image]

Then you can see the secret is added as below:

[image]

Inside the secret your secret value is stored.

[image]